# How to make a button instead of item in knockout.js

Tags: list, knockout.js, grid-layout

I want to have a list of photos aligned in the grid, and in the end of list I want to have a button to upload another one. Typically knockout 'foreach' binding copies content as many times as there are items in the list. For just a list of photos I would do something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
    <li>
        <img ....>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I need a final html to look something like:

```
<ul>
    <li><img ....></li>
    <li><img ....></li>
    <li><img ....></li>
    <li><input ....></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to somehow make knockout generate kind of 'special' item in the end of list?

Comment: Nobody is going to answer this if you don't at least post some code.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking us to code something for you. What have you tried so far? At what point did you run into problems? How can we reproduce this situation to help you fix those problems? Have you searched for existing solutions? If so, why were the solutions that exist so far not solutions that solved your problem? Etc.

Comment: @HansRoerdinkholder, surely no coding is required :) I am just seeking the general approach to accomplish such tasks. Looks like my question was not specific enough, so I added some more information...

Comment: changed my downvote into an unvote, nice edit. Glad to see your question was already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at using the containerless syntax and add an element after the `foreach` like so:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: photos-->
        <li><img ....></li>
        <li><img ....></li>
        <li><img ....></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li><input ....></li>
</ul>
```

**Reference:**

**[See section: Note 4: Using foreach without a container element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)**

> In some cases, you might want to duplicate a section of markup, but
>   you don’t have any container element on which to put a foreach
>   binding.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted! And soooooo ashamed to miss it in documentation....